# I've been coding in JS for about a week. I want to work on some project, do you have any library recommendations?

Tags: library, javascript

I was considering picking up react but I don't know very much about html and css right now. However that is something I want to learn as well. It would be nice to get some library recommendations from people who know more about this than I do.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, but not really an answer, because there is not really a question :-/

It depends on your requirements (if you edit your question to give those, it will be un-held and we will answer). Welcome aboard, bit please read [ask]. We don’t do “best” questions – one man’s best is another man’s worst; see [Is it acceptable to use 'best' in a question?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157/is-it-acceptable-to-use-best-in-a-question) et al.

If you want two way data binding, use Angular(Js) (unfortunately , Google switched AngularJs language from JS to TypeScript & no longer develop the JS version, but millions still use it).

Vue is great & lightweight, similar to Angular in its use of directives, but only has one way data binding out of the box (although you can add 2 way on).

ReactJs is very popular, and might be a good choice if you might later want to use React Native to develop cross-platform Android & iOs apps. They are two separate languages/frameworks, but with a great deal of overlap.

Ember is also extremely popular, but how can I know if it meets your requirements when you don’t have any, other than “best”?

And, of course, JQuery is the one that started it all & still has extremely wide support & following.

In short, please read [ask] and update your question to tell us which features you want, or just google – there are plenty of “best JS” sites out there.

Finally, you say :

> I don't know very much about html and css right now

forget about JS. You need a firm understanding of those first.

Answer (score 0):

VanillaJS was voted the best JS library/frame work last year -

https://www.infoworld.com/article/3306453/the-best-open-source-software-for-software-development.html#slide14

I agree - if I have to code in JS, I'd rather use Vanilla than anything else.  But then, I'm a "boxes full of parts to full functional back end" guy.